# not able to create histogram using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

This code does not work and returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'normed'
```

I think it should work because it is copy-paste from:

https://github.com/dashee87/blogScripts/blob/master/Jupyter/2017-06-04-predicting-football-results-with-statistical-modelling.ipynb

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epl_1617 = pd.read_csv("https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/E0.csv")
epl_1617 = epl_1617[['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG']]
epl_1617 = epl_1617.rename(columns={'FTHG': 'HomeGoals', 'FTAG': 'AwayGoals'})

poisson_pred = np.column_stack([[poisson.pmf(i, epl_1617.mean()[j]) for i in range(8)] for j in range(2)])

plt.hist(epl_1617[['HomeGoals', 'AwayGoals']].values, range(9), 
         alpha=0.7, label=['Home', 'Away'],normed=True, color=["#FFA07A", "#20B2AA"])
```

I am using Python 3.7 and matplotlib 3.5.1

Comment: `normed` has been depricated. Check [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). As suggested there - "Deprecated; use the density keyword argument instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever try to remove

```
'normed=True'
```

from the arguments of plt.hist()?

It may due to version mismatch of matplotlib.pyplot.
Mine is python3.10.10, matplotlib-3.7.0, got similar issue. After removing 'normed=True', I got

[image]

There is another issue in your provided sample code, poisson should be imported first.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
```

Comment: referer to https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html, 'normed' is deprecated, it suggests to use 'density' instead.